# How to find common strings among two very large files?

Tags: string, algorithm, file

I have **two very large files** (and **neither of them would fit in memory**). **Each file has one string** (which doesn't have spaces in it and is either 99/100/101 characters long) **on each line.**

**Update:** The strings are not in any sorted order.
**Update2:** I am working with Java on Windows.

Now I want to figure out the best way **to find out all the strings that occur in both the files.**

I have been thinking about using external merge sort to sort both the files and then do comparison but I am not sure if that would be the best way to do it. Since the strings are mostly around the same length, I was always wondering if computing some kind of a hash for each string would be a good idea, since that should make comparisons between strings easier, but then that would mean I have to store the hashes computed for the strings I have encountered from the files so far so that they can be used later when comparing them with other strings. I am not able to pin down on what exactly would be the best way. I am looking for your suggestions.

When you suggest a solution, also please state if the solution would work if there were more than 2 files and strings which occur in all of them had to be figured out.

Answer (score 18):

You haven't said what platform you're working on, so I assume you're working on Windows, but in the unlikely event that you're on a Unix platform, standard tools will do it for you.

```
sort file1 | uniq > output
sort file2 | uniq >> output
sort file3 | uniq >> output
...
sort output | uniq -d
```

Comment: And in the event that you are on a Windows platform, the simplicity of this solution is so great that it's probably worth finding a Unix box, or installing cygwin.  This is also how I would solve this.

Comment: This doesn't tell which strings are the ones repeated in all files, but output the set union of all files.

Comment: uniq -d deletes singly occurring lines and only prints a single copy of duplicated lines.

Comment: This really is the simplest solution - even if you have to install cygwin on windows (which is relatively painless). It will save you so much time compared to rolling your own.

Comment: Thank you for this one. But I have to handle this using Java in Windows :(

Comment: Runtime is here is basically  O(n log n) where n is the number of lines in the longest file.

Comment: If you want to know how many files each line is common to, then the last line can be modified to: sort output | uniq -c

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it as follows (for any number of files):

- Sort **just 1 file** (#1).
- Walk through each line of the next file (#2) and do a binary search on the #1 file (based on the number of lines).
- If you find the string; write it on another temp file (#temp1).
- After you finished with #2, sort #temp1 go to #3 and do the same search but this time on #temp1, not #1, which should take much less than the first one as this only has repeated lines.
- Repeat this process with new temporary files, deleting previous #temp files. Each iteration should take less and less, as the number of repeated lines diminishes.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how similar the entries within one file is, it might be possible to create a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries) (not tree) from it. Using this trie you can iterate the other file and check each entry if it is inside the trie.

When you have more than 2 files, iterate over one file and build a new trie from the matches. This way the last trie you have will contain all the matches that are contained in all files.

Answer (score 1):

I would sort each file, then use a Balanced Line algorithm, reading one line at a time from one file or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any order to the data in the files? The reason I ask is that though a line by line comparison would take an eternity, going through one file line by line whilst doing a binary search in the other would be much quicker. This can only work if the data is sorted in a particular way though.

Answer (score 0):

I would load both files into two database tables so that each string in the file became a row in the table and use SQL queries to find duplicate rows using a join.

Answer (score 0):

A hash based solution might look like this (in python pseudocode):

```
hashes = dict()
for file in files:
    for line in lines:
        h = md5(line)
        hashes[h] += 1
```

Then loop over again, printing matching lines:

```
for file in files:
    for line in lines:
        h = md5(line)
        if hashes[h] == nfiles:
            print line
            del hashes[h]  # since we only want each once.
```

There are two potential problems.

1. potential hash collisions (which can be mitigated some, but is a risk. )
2. needs to be able to handle a dict (associative array) of size: |uniq lines in all files|

This is O(lines * cost(md5) ).

(if people a fuller python implementation, it's pretty easy to write, I don't know java though!).

Comment: Just curious to know why are you focusing on line rather than word? The question states find the common strings (words) among two large files. Please advise.

Comment: One more question - What is the need to apply hash function? Can't we directly store the string as key value?

Answer (score 0):

To do it in windows, its pretty simple .. 
lets say , you have two files A and B. 'A' files contains the strings you want to search in file B. just open command prompt and use the following command

```
FINDSTR /G:A B > OUTPUT
```

this command is pretty fast and can compare two files very efficiently. The file OUTPUT will contain the strings common in A and B.

if you want to perform the OR operations (strings in B other than A) then use

```
FINDSTR /V /G:A B > OUTPUT
```