# highcharts: Object doesn't support this property or method IE8

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I seem to get this error in IE8 when using highcharts: Object doesn't support this property or method
In Chrome the same site works perfectly!
I dont get any errors in the Chrome debugger.

URL: http://63.gradernord.no

Does somebody have any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet explorer trips up sometimes if a javascript variable has the same name as a html element. Switch your javascript variable name  for windspeed and it should work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14003088/2033671

Comment: That was it Austin, thank you for your help.. Microsoft products keep getting weirder, LOL