# Extending jQuery in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My company recently launched a website and we're getting a JavaScript error often in IE11.

```
Object doesn't support property or method '[ext. func name]' [Internet Explorer 11.0]
```

In our code we're frequently extending jQuery with the following syntax:

```
$.fn.center=function() { ...... };
```

The error message always happens on those functions. Is there a solution to this? Or at least an explanation? I'm ok with changing the code but I'd like to understand why it is happening as well.

I have not been able to reproduce this issue in IE11 myself. The only reason we're able to see the errors is because we're AJAX'ing all clientside errors to ourselves via window.onerror.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?  You say the error occurs in IE11, but then you say you can't reproduce it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie ?

Comment: We're ajaxing JavaScript error messages to ourselves from the client computers. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Adding to `$.fn` is a very common practice, so the mere fact of extending jQuery in that way is unlikely to be your issue.  I would focus efforts on investigation of how you're loading these extensions, to ensure that they are in fact being applied before you try to use them.  Adding any interesting parts of that process to your question may be helpful, as what you've currently provided is not sufficient to provide much more help.

Comment: Thanks for the response jasdeepkhalso. I do not believe that is it. One of our function names is serializeObject and we definitely don't have an HTML element ID'ed that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about jQuery, but if you use compilation for your project, you might consider to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support