# document.getElementById('someId') results in "Object does not support the property or method 'getElementById'"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, getelementbyid

I have a weird JavaScript exception in Internet Explorer 9:

[image: Screenshot]

Translated to English, the message reads:

> Object does not support the property or method 'getElementById'

However, when I execute `document.getElementById` through the JavaScript console, the function is found. In fact, if I execute the entire statement that caused the exception there, it succeeds! (c.f. the screenshot).

What could be the cause of this weirdness? `document` should have a `getElementById` method at all times, should it not? And why would the same statement succeed if I retry it in the debugger?

I can reproduce the problem with Internet Explorer 9, but not IE 11 or Firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you can post some relevant JS code, maybe I could come up with something helpfull.

Comment: http://developer.expressionz.in/blogs/2011/02/18/ie-javascript-error-object-doesn%E2%80%99t-support-this-property-or-method/

Comment: first you should always post some code in order to get better help. second look at @sanki 's comment, where another user faced your problem, and just changed the variable name he used.

Comment: @sanki: That may be relevant, but as I am not declaring any variables in that function, I can not adopt the solution as is. Is there a more specific explanation as to why the variable names need to be different from id attributes of html elements?

Comment: I was trying to find out something worth explaining but couldn't. Here's another link supporting the theory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie. If you don't want to rename your variable do not forget to declare it properly. add "var" for saving the trouble.

Comment: Please do post the answer when you have One, It surely will benefit a lot of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further analysis revealed the following:

As the JavaScript function was declared in event handler attribute on an element, that element became part of the lexical scope chain of the function, causing that element's `document` property to shadow the global declaration of `window.document`. (If this was not clear, I recommend reading [Scope of Event Handlers](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_01.htm#jscript4-CHP-19-SECT-1.6)).

Moreover, before the function was invoked, a jQuery DOM manipulation had replaced that node in the document. This caused Internet Explorer 9 to update that element's document property to point to a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) jQuery created.

Therefore, the function accidentally used the elements `document` property, and got a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) where a full fledged [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) was expected. A DocumentFragment does not feature a `getElementById` method.

I have resolved the issue, and prevented further inferference from the lexical scope chain, but wrapping the event handler into a function created with the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Syntax), which causes it not to inherit the lexical scope.