# What's going on? OpenTextFile.WriteLine error:- Object doesn't support property or method 'WriteLine'

Tags: javascript, activexobject, filesystemobject

Need some advice please peep's...

```
11  <script>
12      fname='C:/Genesis 15/site/portal/proj/htm_app/pkmn/test_2.txt'
13      mode=8 // Open a file for reading
14      create=true // a new file will not be created
15      
16      xfs=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')
17      xfs.OpenTextFile(fname,mode,create)
18      xfs.WriteLine('This text will be added to the end of file')
19      xfs.Close()
20  </script>
```

returns:-

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'WriteLine'
File: default.htm, Line: 18, Column: 3
```

I really don't get it!

what am I missing?

It's the same code I've used in IE since, well, forever...

And now it's popping up with this, AARRGGHH?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie)

Comment: use the return value of the `OpenTextFile` method to write to file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: akonsu cheers!!  can't believe i missed that???!!!   I was just there as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved!

```
    xfs=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')
    fi=xfs.OpenTextFile(fname,mode,create)
    fi.WriteLine('This text will be added to the end of file')
    fi.Close()
```