# Object does not support property or method 'init' while initializing jcrop plugin in IE8

Tags: jquery

I am getting "Object does not support property or method 'init'" error while initializing Jcrop plugin in IE8 only.
Works in other browsers.
Below is my code snipet.

```
 var area = $("#picture").Jcrop({
                setSelect: [0, 0, 50, 50],
                aspectRatio: 1,
                handles: ['n', 's', 'e', 'w'],
                onChange: function (c) {
                    onEnd(c);
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Try this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie

Comment: but my problem is not with the id or class name. it shows error in this.init() in Jcrop plugin.