# "The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid" error when loading React app that uses Webpack in Windows Edge 13

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microsoft-edge

I'm totally stumped on this error. I've been investigating this for days to no avail.

It is a fairly complex web app that uses React, Webpack and Babel to run. The error I get in the Edge console seems to related to Webpack, so I've added a couple of polyfills but that didn't change anything.

I haven't seen anyone else encountering this error, which I find surprising. I've updated all node packages but that didn't fix it either.

Here is the package.json, I currently have:

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.22",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^1.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.22.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.7",
    "graphiql": "0.3.1",
    "history": "1.13.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.1.1",
    "jsxstyle": "^0.0.17",
    "mockdate": "1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.10.2",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^0.14.0",
    "react-chartjs": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "react-relay": "^0.4.0",
    "react-router": "1.0.0-rc3",
    "react-router-relay": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.3",
    "superagent": "^1.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^3.1.30",
    "babel-jest": "^5.3.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint": "^0.23",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "0.0.7",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.2.2",
    "jest-cli": "^0.5.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.0-beta3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node node_modules/.bin/jest --verbose --runInBand",
    "build": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "",
    "scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/babel-jest",
    "preprocessorIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "testPathDirs": [
      "<rootDir>/src/"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-relay/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-router/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-sticky/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jsxstyle/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/underscore/",
      "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/",
      "<rootDir>/src/components/delay/",
      "<rootDir>/src/mutations/",
      "<rootDir>/src/components/react-wrapper"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone see anything obvious as to why the app wouldn't run at all in Edge 13? The error I get in the console is:

[image: Error in Edge console]

Anything that gets me on the right track, I'd appreciate!

---

**Edit**

My webpack.config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    academy: "./src/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "../website/app/assets/javascripts/academy/[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ["babel-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js"]
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? "eval-source-map" : null
};
```

Comment: works in chrome without an error?

Comment: Does the site work without webpack? What does your webpack.config.js look like? It looks like Edge is reporting that there's an error somewhere in the string being eval()ed, but can't actually tell you where.

Comment: Yes, works in Chrome/Firefox/Safari perfectly. I'm investigating an issue in IE11 at the same time but the error is different. In IE11 I get: "Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat'" in my console. In IE11, the error is from here I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie

Comment: @MikeDimmick I've added the webpack file above. Part of the app is written in ES6, so I have webpack configured with Babel. I can't see it working without it...