# IE8 issue - Object doesn't support property or method error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

This is the problem..

[image]

code in -- cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js  file

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader=(function(){var b=document.documentElement,g=document.querySelector(".cbp-af-header"),e=false,a=100;function f(){window.addEventListener("scroll",function(h){if(!e){e=true;setTimeout(d,250)}},false)}function d(){var h=c();if(h>=a){classie.add(g,"cbp-af-header-shrink")}else{classie.remove(g,"cbp-af-header-shrink")}e=false}function c(){return window.pageYOffset||b.scrollTop}f()})();
```

Searched for this issue and found this thread [SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie)

**"html element id has the same id as some variable in the javascript function"..**

Is this the solution.. What does this mean.. I have no idea.. can anyone help me out..

Comment: Use the unminimized version and see if it gives you a better error message.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several other issues too, but as a quick look i found this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",
```

Where `addEventListener` is not supported in IE8 and `querySelector()` method is also partially supported. So, you can either have a fallback like:

```js
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {
  var b = document.documentElement,
    g = document.getElementsByClassName("cbp-af-header")[0],
    e = false,
    a = 100;

  function f() {
    window.onscroll = function(h) {
      if (!e) {
        e = true;
        setTimeout(d, 250)
      }
    };
  }

  function d() {
    var h = c();
    if (h >= a) {
      classie.add(g, "cbp-af-header-shrink")
    } else {
      classie.remove(g, "cbp-af-header-shrink")
    }
    e = false
  }

  function c() {
    return window.pageYOffset || b.scrollTop
  }
  f()
})();
```

Comment: Thank u for ur quick response @Jai.. If that is the problem can u giv me a solution for that?

Comment: I tried this and it shows the same error but on : line 16 Char 5