# QlikView with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, custom-controls, qlikview

I am trying to develop a custom object extension in QlikView using d3.js

First I tried to manually code everything, but I encountered a error like the figure below. It looks like QlikView does not support some d3_v2.js methods.

I also tried using a newer version of d3 (d3.min.js)...

Ultimately, I tried using a tested custom component (https://qvextanimatedscatter.codeplex.com/) , but it also ran on the same error...

Any clues?
Does QlikView has a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you google the error message? See here;

[SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie)

> After some days searching the Internet I found that this error usually
>   occurs when an html element id has the same id as  some variable in
>   the javascript function.  After changing the name of one of them my
>   code was working fine.

It might solve the problem.

Comment: I already changed the names of all variables.. I didn't work. Look like QlikView has some bug