# Object doesn't support property or method 'jqEasyCounter'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Jquery character counter and I am getting this error with IE. "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqEasyCounter'" Firefox and Chrome work well.

What can I change in the code to ensure it works for IE?

Thanks

Javascript code below:

```
 (
 function(a)
 {
     a.fn.extend({jqEasyCounter:function(b)
           {
                return this.each(function()
                     {
                           var f=a(this),e=a.extend({
                               maxChars:100,maxCharsWarning:80,msgFontSize:"12px",
                               msgFontColor:"#000000",msgFontFamily:"Arial",
                               msgTextAlign:"right",msgWarningColor:"#F00",msgAppendMethod:"insertAfter"},b);
                                    if(e.maxChars<=0)
                                        {
                                           return
                                        }
                                        var d=a('<div class="jqEasyCounterMsg">&nbsp;</div>');
                                        var c={"font-size":e.msgFontSize,"font-family":e.msgFontFamily,
                                            color:e.msgFontColor,"text-align":e.msgTextAlign,width:f.width(),opacity:0};
                                        d.css(c);
                                        d[e.msgAppendMethod](f);
                                        f.bind("keydown keyup keypress",g).bind("focus paste",function()
                                            {
                                                setTimeout(g,10)
                                            }).bind("blur",function()
                                                {
                                                    d.stop().fadeTo("fast",0);
                                                    return false
                                            });
                                        function g() {
                                            var i=f.val(),h=0;
                                            for (var x = 0; x < i.length; x++) {
                                                if (i.codePointAt(x) < 128) {
                                                    h = h + 1;
                                                } else {
                                                    h = h + 2;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        if(h>=e.maxChars){
                                                i=i.substring(0,e.maxChars)
                                            }
                                            if(h>e.maxChars){
                                                var j=f.scrollTop();
                                                f.val(i.substring(0,e.maxChars));
                                                f.scrollTop(j)
                                            }
                                            if(h>=e.maxCharsWarning){
                                                   d.css({color:e.msgWarningColor})
                                            }
                                            else {
                                              d.css({color:e.msgFontColor})
                                            }
                                        d.html("Characters: "+h+"/"+e.maxChars);
                                        d.stop().fadeTo("fast",1)
                                        }
                            })
                    }
                 })
 })(jQuery);
```

Javascript on actual page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function charCount(){
        $('.countable1').jqEasyCounter({
            'maxChars': 250,
            'maxCharsWarning': 250
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: See answer here. This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie

Comment: interesting find. I don't see anywhere with collusion. is there an easy way to find it?

Comment: Do any of your html elements have an ID of jqEasyCounter?  That could be your collision.

Comment: No sir, none of the IDs have jqEasy or anything like that.